# Capabilities of Amazon SNS Mobile Push Notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have a project in my mind where an administrator sends a push notification to all users from his Smartphone, if a shopkeeper has to notify all his customers for instance. The procedure will be as follows:

```
1. Admin Mobile-to-Cloud
2. Cloud-to-UserMobiles
```

Does Amazon SNS support this procedure ?. I have made a quick research and it seems like that it only supports Cloud-to-Mobile and not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Mobile SDK for Android and iOS support AWS SNS API, so you can easily implement the functionality by going through the steps in this link if you're using Android:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html

Remember to implement the functionality in step 4 in an Android project instead of Java (this will be an administrator app in your case).